# Trying to remove commit messages involving a long filename in Git revision history

Tags: linux, windows, git, svn

So I created a file with a very long name (around 300 chars) to test something, but I no longer need it and have deleted it.. I did this in my svn repository. Then I cloned this svn repository into a git repository using git svn clone, which didn't give me any issue.  However, the creation and deletion of this file is now recorded in my git commit history..

This is giving me issues when using git commands like filter-branch. Error is 'Filename too long cannot check out index'

I know the commit ids involving the particular file. Is there a way to get rid of these commits in the 'revision history' that will involve the file with the long name..?

Note: I performed the above on a Windows machine, but I tried moving to Linux machine and tried the filter branch command there as well but still getting the same 'filename too long issue'. I am new to Linux, so is there any setting that I missed out to handle long filenames?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Linux has a limit for a filename length (not for path), probably you have hit that one

Answer (score 0):

You should use [git filter-branch with --index-filter](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch#git-filter-branch---index-filterltcommandgt) so that you don't have to deal with filesystem limitations